# What other frameworks should ASP.Net programmers consult for code inspiration?

Tags: .net, asp.net

What other frameworks should ASP.Net programmers consult for code inspiration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broaden your search - don't look just at ASP.NET MVC. Different approaches will help you better understand things you want to do.

Some suggestions:

- [RoR](http://www.rubyonrails.org/)
- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Grails](http://grails.org/)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET programmers should have a look at the ASP.NET MVC framework for alternatives on how to do stuff on basically the same platform, but still more like some other, popular frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Without a doubt you need to be looking at [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/default.aspx?wwwaspnetrdirset=1)

Answer (score 0):

Well ASP.NET in pretty much unique in it's own respect. You've got user controls, master pages, web forms, a plethora of hooks for IIS...

I'd say you should look into other peoples code for inspiration, see how they've done it.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a pretty neat hooking framework that allows you to extend modules and the core code without forking it off by editing it and being forced into remaking changes after every new version.

Rails has some pretty incredible utilities (like rake) that make database migrations a snap and settings up projects a lot easier.

Django has a really clean codebase and fast development time.